# Sticky navigation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, css, navigation, managed-metadata

I've added some styling to the `s4-titlerow` for branding purposes and need to make it sticky. What's the best way to do this without getting the title stuck as well? I've added `position: fixed;` to `s4-titlerow` but then the `pageTitle` overlaps all the text in the body:

[image]

```
#s4-titlerow {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #DBDCDE;
    padding-top: 19px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 150;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this

```
#s4-titlerow {
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #DBDCDE;
    padding-top: 19px;
    padding-bottom: 28px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
    top:65px;
}

#s4-workspace {
    margin-top: 97px;
}
```

Comment: No, that doesn't do quite what I want - I need the top navigation to be sticky but the title to scroll with the page. That just pushes the title up to overlap the top navigation.

Comment: in that case what you can do is locate the heading 1 (h1) in the master page with the id "pageTitle" and move it under DeltaPlaceHolderMain. then it will scroll with the content